# dynamically render vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have vue template data as string. For example,
`String s = "<div>{{myData}}</div>"`

And now I want to render in my already defined vue component.

```
<template>
<div>
   HERE I NEED TO PLACE THE STRING
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data: {
    myData: "IRONMAN"
  },
}
</script>
```

Now I want the output as `IRONMAN`

How can i achieve this? Pleas help.
Thanks

Comment: `this.template = Vue.compile('<div>{{myData}}</div>').render`  looks promising. [source](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/193#issuecomment-265125819)

Comment: Is there any reason to make the div not an child compontent itself?

Comment: From where is this `String s` coming?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have a single file component and do this - I have one called `Dynamic.vue` which accepts a HTML string - I use this to allow the users to generate their own templates and the bindings all match up properly, something like:

```js
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      someVar: 'Test'
    }
  },
  props: {
    templateHtml: {
      templateHtml: true,
      type: String
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.$options.template = this.templateHtml
  }
}
</script>
```

If you were to call it like:

```
this.htmlData = '<div>Hello - {{{someVar}}</div>'
....
<my-dynamic-component :template-html="htmlData" />`
```

You would see the output

> Hello Test

You would then omit the `<template>` part in the SFC.

Note: In order for this to work, you must also have the Vue Compiler included in your project (as this handles compiling the SFC into render functions which Vue uses to display data).

This link: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CLI can give more information about including the Vue Compiler.

Comment: How to  include Vue Compiler in my project

Comment: Are you using webpack? How is your project compiled? Added a link to the main post for you to read.