# Vue functional component throws _c is not defined error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I created the following functional component using render method:

```
import Vue from "vue"

const { render, staticRenderFns } = Vue.compile(`<div>Hello World</div>`)

Vue.component("HelloWorld", {
    functional: true,
    render,
    staticRenderFns
})
```

And then in `App.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <HelloWorld />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            compiled: false
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

And I get the error:

> `_c is not defined`.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: See this -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369839/dynamically-insert-child-components-inside-vuejs2-data-without-compile-or-abus  you need to import your component

Comment: Import my component? But it's already declared as a global component. And also, this issue is only with the functional component. Normal component works fine i.e. if I remove `functional: true` it works fine.

Comment: How about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901607/dynamically-render-vue-template/57901736#57901736

Comment: @webnoob Damn that's useful. Thank you very much. Although not sure about functional component.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, the render functions generated by `Vue.compile` cannot be used to render a functional component.

Comment: Oh crap! That's a bummer. Is there any way to build functional component by passing template string?

Comment: I don't think so. The template compiler bundled with Vue is not able to compile functional templates. I believe only the compiler provided with `vue-loader` can do this at build time.

Comment: May I ask why you require the use of `Vue.compile`? Maybe there's a better solution to your problem.

Comment: Actually I fetch html from the server and render it as a Vue component.

Comment: Is what you're fetching plain HTML or is it a Vue template? If it's sanitized HTML then you can just use `v-html` to render it.

Comment: HTML is sanitized. User is allowed to create dynamic components by themselves. They define id and html and I use these to bake a component and therefore user can write <input-widget /> for example to render this component.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing to creating a functional component from a template string would involve parsing the string to get the element type and attributes and render as:

```
Vue.component("hello-world", {
      functional: true,
      render: function(createElement, context) {
        return createElement(
          "div",
         'example text'         
        );
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Decade Moon already mentioned, **render functions returned by `Vue.compile` cannot be used as render function in functional component**. Reason for that becomes clear when you inspect the signature of the function returned by `Vue.compile`:

```
const render: (createElement: any) => VNode
```

As you can see, function is missing second argument, which is required for render functions of functional components:

```
render: (createElement: CreateElement, context: RenderContext<Record<never, any>>) => VNode
```

Functional components are instanceless. That means no `this` context - that's why additional `context` parameter is needed to carry props\listeners etc.

Also if you look at [this post on Vue forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-compile-referenceerror--h-is-not-defined/3928):

> The render function created by compile() relies on private properties of the component. To have access to those properties, the method has to be assigned to a property of the component(so it has access to those properties via `this`)

However that doesn't mean you can't create functional component with template. You can, you are just not able to use `Vue.compile` to pass template text dynamically. If you are fine with static template, you can do it like this:

```
// component.vue

<template functional>
  <div>Hello World</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "hello"
};
</script>
```

...and use the component like any other SFC (single file component = VUE file)

If you need dynamic template text, just use non-functional component instead...